# Change ip address in windows every x time using python

Tags: python, python-2.7

How I can use Python to change my IP address after X period of time?

Comment: Are you trying to change your private address on a LAN, or your LAN's public address? Is your LAN a Windows domain? Do you get your IP address by DHCP, BOOTP, static assignment, choosing whatever you want, or something different? Do you have admin rights on your machine? On the domain controller? There's no general answer to this, and the specific answer (if there is one) depends on what specifically you're trying to do. "How do I release my DHCP lease and request a new one" is reasonable question, especially if you can describe how you'd do it manually; this isn't.

Answer (score -1):

You can try something like this:

```
import os
os.system("netsh interface ip set address "Local Area Connection" static 192.168.0.10 255.255.255.0 192.168.0.1 1")
print "IP ADRESS CHANGED!"
```

Comment: Could you please explean this command: `static 192.168.0.10 255.255.255.0 192.168.0.1 1`

Comment: @yuyb0y That's windows netsh command, more info is provided here:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257748